# ionic framework fixed header with left menu with child view with back button

Tags: ionic-framework, header, fixed, back-button

I am new to ionic framework. I have a requirement where I have login page. Once user has successfully logged in I have to show view with header bar with menu but to on left (clicking on menu shows left menu bar with navigation links). The header bar will always have fixed text I.e. Company name. Below that I have to show view ex. Search text box. Once user clicks on search button user would be redirected to results page. This page will have search results with back button above search result. Be informed this page will also have header with menu button and company name.

To summarize - fixed header with left menu and fixed label. Child view will have optional back button below header

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Was trying to modify ionic left menu template.